# Value still inserting, even though query encased in if statement which should stop it from doing so?

Tags: php, mysql

I really don't know what's going on here, I've been racking my brain for ages trying to figure this out;

I have the variable `$overflow = $_POST['overflow'];` and then the following code:

```
if($overflow != "" || $overflow != "Overflow link"){
    $query = "DELETE FROM links WHERE overflow='YES'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "INSERT INTO links (link, overflow) VALUES ('$overflow','YES') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE overflow=VALUES(overflow)";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The idea is if `$overflow` is empty or holds the default value, it isn't inserted, but if it's a valid value the already existing entry for it is deleted (because I can't make the column unique), and it's re-inserted.

Anyone have any idea was to why it's inserting on ANY value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a serious SQL injection security vulnerability here.  What happens when the user posts `overflow='; DROP TABLE links; --`?

Comment: It inserts the value that's posted with the form field `name=overflow` so I don't see the need to do that, as that in and of itself validates that it's being set, doesn't it? :O

Comment: If you can't make it unique, that implies it has duplicate values. In that case, which value do you replace when inserting a new row?

Comment: @cdhowie: It's for a private client, for a really minuscule underground project and he'll be the only one with access to the script anyway (basic security measures, can't post unless a session is validated).

Comment: @Pixel No, there's an injection vulnerability, since you're not saying anything about the *value* of that input. Even apart from that, you always need to escape values to make sure your SQL doesn't break. See http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Comment: @Pixelatron: Just because only one or two people will have access to the site doesn't excuse sloppy coding.   :P

Comment: deceze - My first comment was based on his original comment, he edited it. @NullUserException - overflow contains either "YES" or "NO", the majority (cept 1) row contain "NO", thus it can't be given a unique key (from my understanding anyway). This deals with updating the row with the value "YES".

Comment: Both answers pinpointed your problem.  However, just reading your description, there has to be a better solution than doing some sort of bizarre deletion just to insert a row. Something is wrong with your design.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably do `UPDATE links SET link='$overflow' WHERE overflow='YES'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If not empty or not *some value*".

Well, it cannot be empty *and* "some value" at the same time, so this condition is *always* true. You're looking for:

```
if ($overflow != "" && $overflow != "Overflow link")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!empty($overflow) && $overflow != "Overflow link"){
    $query = "DELETE FROM links WHERE overflow='YES'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "INSERT INTO links (link, overflow) VALUES ('$overflow','YES') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE overflow=VALUES(overflow)";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: empty() is useless here, just `$overflow` is enough

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel just going by the OP's statement... "if $overflow is empty or holds the default value it isn't inserted".  Maybe I took it to literally.